Adding row splits data validation Google sheets
In the Test spreadsheet here I created a budget table that has dependent dropdown lists. When you select a category in the Main table, column F, in the Subcategory column (G) another dropdown list appears, based on the Category selection. It works fine and I am happy with it except for when I add a row in the main table, data validation in column G (Subcategory) splits and range reference is not good anymore.
Is there a way to stop Google sheets to split my data validation rule when I add a row?
Interestingly, adding a row does not split data validation rule in column F (category), but just in column F (Subcategory).
Thanks in advance!


Added one possible approach to your test sheet:
I placed the backend dependant-dropdown setup in the same tab instead of a separate one(Preparation tab) & now data validation rules can withstand the insertion/deletion of rows within that range
=map(F3:F38;lambda(Σ;torow(ifna(filter(Ranges!E2:N;Ranges!E1:N1=Σ));1)))



Thanks. I will use this formula. Still, I don't understand why is only the second data validation split (in column F). Based on the suggested solutions, it needs to be on the same sheet.

F points to absolute reference range $E$1:$N$1 and G points to relative reference range $F1:1

ALTERNATIVE APPROACH
Aside from @Rockinfreashow's way, you may use Vlookup formula:
this will not split the data validation rule you've set while adding rows.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F3:F,Ranges!E10:J19,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE),""))

Result:

Just like in @rockinfreakshow's , you have to hide the columns.

In this method, You have to transpose first what you have set in the Ranges sheet like below:
=TRANSPOSE(E1:N6)


Ref: Have Vlookup Return Multiple Columns in Google Sheets
